# How can I improve usage data sharing?

Tags: app-store-connect

I would like more users to agree to share app usage data with the developer.

I can show an alertview asking you to go to the settings and enable it there, but it would be more userfriendly to enable it directly in the application after the user's permission.

Is there any way to do so?